# Is it good idea to create a Sarcastic tone for provocative thoughts

Tags: style

For writing a editorial note covering some misjudgement facts (basically criticism of new policies based on failed results), I am writing in a sarcastic tone to get the message clear and effective as far as getting reactions (positively in action and ideal manner).

Would that be good idea considering that the majority of the readers is aged between 18-27?

Or any other manner you can suggest.

It's a students' college magazine raising academic issues, a kind of indirect communication bridge between students and the faculty to get their attention in their implemented rules, covering tuition-fees, assignments, publications of papers and views on new rules and their expected results.

Comment: I'm having some difficulty understanding you. Are you writing an editorial in a publication? What does "some misjudgment facts" mean? Does the venue have a history of sarcastic editorial voice? Why do you think sarcasm is more "clear and effective" than writing objectively and non-emotionally?

Comment: I'm afraid I have to close this; this question is unanswerable in its present form. Lauren's comment addresses many of its problems: For what sort of publication are you writing? Is this voice appropriate to the venue? Please consider clarifying this and we'd be happy to consider reopening.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum - Thanks for reply , now i have included info , but it seems closed now as off-topic & not constructive ,if so please let me know , so i will delete this question as seemed inappropriate.

Answer (score 2):

If the intent of your article is to *persuade*, then sarcasm is rarely an effective tactic. Overt sarcasm will cause those who already agree with you will snigger along with you, while those who don't agree will be irritated. Subtle sarcasm runs the danger of being misinterpreted as sincerity. In either case, sarcasm is rarely an effective choice for an editorial.

You'll notice that printed media very rarely use sarcasm in their editorial pieces. It is somewhat more common on blogs and other online media, where the standards of formality are lower, but the best bloggers still use it sparingly. My recommendation is to stay away.

Comment: Thanks a lot for Not-Recommending sarcasm as theme , since it stands as Negative-feedback to be published in College magazine , which i previously thought would be better .